# How to fix "You are not allowed to use "Application""

Tags: macos, terminal, command-line, error

[image]

How do I fix this message, I am Admin, Mobile. Even if i login to a root account this message still appears. I have iTerm so if any commands need to be inputted to fix this problem I can still do it. This also happens with activity monitor. 
Mavericks

Comment: did you run permissions repair ?

Comment: @Buscar웃 I just did that, still have the same issue. It was owned by my school (I have just graduated), but it is mine now, so obviously it's something that the 'I.T guys' have done, just trying to work out how to reverse this action.

Comment: in that case I suggest you restore the operating system with cmd-r to eliminate other issues down the line. Just guessing here, the IT guys might have disabled the Terminal app. You could also try just making a new user and see if it works with that.

Answer (score 2):

Old question, but I'll answer it anyway:

This message is from JAMF's Casper Suite. You can remove all the JAMF nonsense with either `sudo /usr/sbin/jamf removeFramework` or `sudo /usr/local/bin/jamf removeFramework` (depending on the version installed).

Comment: big vote up for recognizing the gui and providing a relevant answer